# Trouble compiling with gcc through virtual machine

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, virtual-machine, traceroute

I'm currently trying to compile my file `traceroutet.c` through a virtual machine running Ubuntu, which I think is causing the problem. I'm also accessing files through my university's VPN, could that cause issues?

Whenever I try to compile through the vm's terminal using `gcc -o traceroutet traceroutet.c` I get this error:

`traceroutet.c:13:16: fatal error: ip.h: No such file or directory`

`compilation terminated`

The thing is, my header files are saved in the same folder as my source, so I thought `gcc -o` would work here? I've also tried using `-I/h/SCC203/Lab 2/ip.c` when compiling too, but I get a similar error.

I've been using `gcc` a while now and never had a problem with it, so I'm guessing this is something to do with the virtual machine or VPN?

Comment: `-I/h/SCC203/Lab 2/ip.c` is wrong anyway: it contains a space, and the space must be escaped, like `-I/h/SCC203/Lab\ 2` (is `ip.c` REALLY a name of directory that contains ip.h?) Anyway, it would help if you show us your #include directive.

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to escape the space.

Yeah, and I've tried it as ip.c and ip.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt very much that the error is related to the virtual machine.

I think it depends on how you #include your ip.h: if you write `#include "ip.h"` (note the double quotes), then you make the compiler to look for 'ip.h' located in the same directory as the .c file. It's implementation-defined whether the compiler would continue searching among the system headers. Since you are most likely trying to include a system-wide `ip.h` and not your own IP-related header file, you should include it with angle brackets (and with the correct relative path): `#include <linux/ip.h>`.

Comment: Thank you! adding `linux/` in the `#include` statement made all the difference!